# How set value spinner when change textEdit of preferenceScreen?

Tags: android, android-intent, spinner, textedit, preferencescreen

How to change the value of TextEdit of preference screen, I want that TextEdit of MainActivity  to be changed. How can I do it?.

```
    @Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
        String key) {
    if (key.equals(PrefUserName)) {

        SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplication());

        String textoEditTextPreference = sharedPref.getString(key,
                "");
        // Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);


        //Here I want add value spinner of main activity...
        // Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toast.makeText(
                getApplication(),
                "New name of user: "
                        + textoEditTextPreference, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
```

Comment: Hi, could you fix the identation on your one comment there, that's code?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand what your question is:
You should use SharedPreference Editor

```
SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = sharedPref.edit();
prefeditor.putString(key, "");
prefeditor.commit();
```